# Jackson XMLWrapper failing to deserialize this xml into pojo?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-deserialization, fasterxml

Consider the given xml below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Records>
    <Record>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku1</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku2</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku3</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku4</Prop>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku10</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku20</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku30</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku40</Prop>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

Now consider these Pojos that I have created(removing getter and setters for brevity).

```java
public class Records {
    private List<Record> records;
}

public class Record {
    private List<Prop> props;
}

public class Prop {
    // I want to capture name attribute
    private String name;
    // But I also want to capture what comes inside Prop element as well. This would then have values like sku1, sku2 etc
    private String text;
}
```

Now I have code using XMLWrapper like this.

```java
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.xml"); // the above XML is sample.xml
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().build();
Records records = xmlMapper.readValue(file, Records.class); // this line is failing
```

But I am getting an error like this

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Record" (class com.example.demo.model.xml.Records), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "records"])
```

Comment: Should be `@XmlElement(name = "Record") private List<Record> records;` to match the element names. Same principal goes for `Prop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine the [`@JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) annotation with the [`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) annotation that indicates the wrapper element to use with a `Collection`: in this case the optional property `useWrapping` is set to *false* to explicitly disable the wrapping:

```
public class Records {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Record")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Record> records;
}

public class Record {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Prop")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Prop> props;
}

public class Prop {
    //<Prop name="commerce">sku1</Prop> name is an attribute with value commerce
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName= "name", isAttribute = true)
    private String name;
    
    //<Prop name="commerce">sku1</Prop> sku1 is the text inside the Prop tags
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works. And even without some of these annotation and just using @JsonProperty I was able to get it to work as well. Not sure how, but it worked. Posted an answer for if anyone would be interested in future.

Comment: @theprogrammer You are welcome. I saw your solution and it contains less code than mine, disabling unwrapper globally with defaultUseWrapper(false) is certainly the most optimal solution if the classes are like the ones you included in your question. In the case you had a different model of class it is possible you should have annotate every class locally and not more globally.

Answer (score 2):

Even without the XML annotations(for the most part), this solution seemed to work for me. Posting for posterity.

Step 1: Disable wrapping.

```java
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample.xml"); 
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build();
Records records = xmlMapper.readValue(file, Records.class);
```

Step 2: Update pojos with JsonProperty annotation(with only exception being getting inner value using @JacksonXmlText. Note removing setters and getters for brevity.

```java
public class Records {
    @JsonProperty("Record")
    private List<Record> records;
}

public class Record {
    @JsonProperty("Prop")
    private List<Prop> props;
}

public class Prop {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String text;
}
```

The above worked for me.