# How to use Jackson to deserialize using feign?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I have a third party endpoint which returns data in xml with Content-Type as `text/xml;charset=UTF-8`. I want to use feign to hit this endpoint and deserialize the xml into my pojo.

I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251449/jackson-xmlwrapper-failing-to-deserialize-this-xml-into-pojo/) regarding just deserializing from a sample xml file(and I got the required answer). However while using feign, the suggested solution doesn't work.

This is the xml that endpoint returns.

```java
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Records>
    <Record>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku1</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku2</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku3</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku4</Prop>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku10</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku20</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku30</Prop>
        <Prop name="commerce">sku40</Prop>
    </Record>
</Records>
```

And this is my feign service and corresponding feign config which I got from [openfeign](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#jaxb) documentation itself.

```java
@FeignClient(value = "api-service", url = "http://localhost:3000", configuration = MyFeignConfig.class)
public interface MyFeignService {

    @GetMapping(value = "/skus", consumes = "text/xml")
    Records getData();

}

@Configuration
public class MyFeignConfig {

    @Bean
    public Decoder feignDecoder() {
        JAXBContextFactory jaxbFactory = new JAXBContextFactory.Builder()
                .withMarshallerJAXBEncoding("UTF-8")
                .build();
        return new JAXBDecoder(jaxbFactory);
    }
}
```

And these are my pojos(removing getters and setters for brevity)

```java
public class Records {
    @JsonProperty("Record")
    private List<Record> records;
}

public class Record {
    @JsonProperty("Prop")
    private List<Prop> props;
}

public class Prop {
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JacksonXmlText
    private String text;
}
```

And this is how I am calling the feign

```java
...
Records records = myFeignService.getData();
...
```

Is this the right way to implement something like this? This seems to not work and whatever I try to do to fix it ends up with some new problem. So I am wondering if there is a simpler way to hit an endpoint using feign and deserialize the response into my java objects?

Comment: You seem to have a JAXB decoder and Jackson annotations. I’m afraid you’re going to have to pick one technology and stick to it, not mix and match…